# EF Many to Many Inserting Records into Main table as well as join table

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, fluent

I have an odd situation with a many to many relationship and inserting data.
Table 1 (Region):

```
public class Region
{
    public Region()
    {
        SessionList = new List<Session>();
        UserProfileList = new List<UserProfile>();
        LeagueEventList = new List<LeagueEvent>();
    }
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Session> SessionList { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfileList { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LeagueEvent> LeagueEventList { get; set; }


}
```

Config file for Region Table:

```
    public class RegionConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Region>
{
    public RegionConfig()
    {
        HasKey<int>(r => r.RegionId);
        Property(r => r.RegionId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
```

And for Table 2(LeagueEvent) we have the following:

```
public class LeagueEvent
{
    public LeagueEvent()
    {
        LeagueEventDetails = new List<LeagueEventDetail>();
        RegionIds = new List<Region>();
        LeagueEventRegistrations = new List<LeagueEventRegistration>();
    }
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public int VenueId { get; set; }
    public virtual Venue venue { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LeagueEventDetail> LeagueEventDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Region> RegionIds { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LeagueEventRegistration> LeagueEventRegistrations { get; set; }
}
```

With the following config file:

```
public class LeagueEventConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<LeagueEvent>
{
    public LeagueEventConfig()
    {
        HasKey<int>(e => e.EventId);
        Property(e => e.EventId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        HasRequired(u => u.venue).WithMany(w => w.LeagueEventList).HasForeignKey(f=> f.VenueId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasMany<Region>(r => r.RegionIds).WithMany(e => e.LeagueEventList).Map(ler =>
            {
                ler.MapLeftKey("EventId");
                ler.MapRightKey("RegionId");
                ler.ToTable("EventRegion");

            });
    }
}
```

What is happening is upon attempted insert of a League Event which can span multiple regions which is why I have RegionIds the entity is showing the correct RegionId value(s) prior to insert and save. However, after inserted and upon inspecting the tables it shows:

New Record created correctly in LeagueEvent

New Record(s) created in EventRegion with the correct EventId(s) but with new RegionIds

New Records created in the Region table with the RegionName value duplicated.

Unless I have misunderstood there never should be a new record created in Region from a League Event insert. Am I misunderstanding how fluent handles join tables?

**UPDATE**
I removed the .map command and tested it that way. EF went ahead and created the table but the same problem kept occurring.

So now I manually created the EventRegion table and updated Events and Regions ICollections to point to that table.  Now it is inserting records with the correct values from the Regions table but a 0 value from the Events table. It also IS NOT inserting records into the Region table like before.

What seems to be happening is the EventRegion records from the collection are being inserted before the actual event hence the 0 value for EventId in EventRegion.

Odd as it is I would have thought that would generate an error. If you need any code snippets for the update let me know.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I never was able to find a solution. I removed the .map statement and then manually created the join table. Everything is working as intended now. Just would have been nice to figure out the issue.